# Find determinant, matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Sry, it could be easy, but i can’t solve this. Can you help me to find determinant, sry for bad resolution.[image]

Please transcribe by editing this template:

$\left|\matrix{
1&x&\cdots& x^n\\
a_{11}&1 &\cdots& x^{n-1}\\
\vdots&\vdots&  \ddots& \vdots\\
a_{n1}&a_{n2}&\cdots & 1
}
\right
|$

Comment: Hint: Let $M$ be your matrix and $\eta$ be the matrix with superdiagonal $1$ and $0$ elsewhere. $(I - x\eta)M $ will be a triangular matrix.

Comment: Have you tried $n=1,2,3$? Ask [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=det+%5B%5B1%2Cx%2Cx%5E2%2Cx%5E3%5D%2C%5Ba%2C1%2Cx%2Cx%5E2%5D%2C%5Bb%2Cc%2C1%2Cx%5D%2C%5Bd%2Ce%2Cf%2C1%5D%5D)